# Windows 2012R2 hyper-v guest diskless - boot from iscsi guide?

Tags: hyper-v, boot, windows-server-2012-r2, iscsi, guest

I am attempting to build a generation 2 W2012R2 hyper-v server guest that, configured with no disk or vhd , will select it's iscsi o/s disk via Microsoft dhcp and boot Windows 2012 R2.  Note that I want the iscsi connection to happen in the hyper-v guest, not at the server level.

My hyper-v server is equipped with Intel x540-t2 Nics dedicated for ISCSI use, but I expect the hyper-v guest will likely see the virtual adapter as the standard Hyper-vVirtual Ethernet adapter.

Is it possible to construct a system like this?  Can someone refer me to a guide that will assist me with this?

I have been going round in circles with iPXE without success so far :-(

Thanks,
Doug Coleman

Answer (score 2):

On the host, you have to create a second virtual network that contains your iSCSI NIC's. Then you can add a NIC to the guest attached to that network. That gives you access to the iSCSI network inside the guest.

However, Hyper-V does not support booting guests directly from iSCSI. You have to chainload in to iPXE or something similar. Hopefully you already know that.

Comment: Are you going to be able to use a Type-2 VM if chainloading via iPXE is required?